# heroku db: can I access from local after deploy? or how to get server ssh access info?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I deploy postgresql from `heroku` and get db address like 'postgresql://hayat:randompassword@localhost:5432/~'.

After I deploy it, can I access from local to this DB?
or How to get ssh server access information in this case?

Comment: Yes, you can do this (though the URL won't be to `localhost`). Have you tried it? That would have taken less time than posting this question.

Comment: Can u tell me how i can do that?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You know that Heroku will give you the connection information... just use it.